# IE7 DropDownList Render Issues

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-7

I have a dropdownlist that renders like this in IE7:

[image]

That same dropdownlist renders like this in IE8 & IE9:

[image]

What do I need to do to get it to render the same in IE7 as it does in ie8 and ie9?

Answer (score 1):

Your can change your font for the dropdown list. Set it to Helveitca, Arial. or use it the other way round to match font system of IE7 to match IE8/9. but as far as the button or the style is considered you have to use stylesheet to format the dropdownlist display. It is because the IE7 default graphics are not same as IE8/9 default. You have to edit your style sheet to give universal look to your display using CSS or themes.